# Strange MX Record behaviour / Google Apps

Tags: mx-record, g-suite

If I check my DNS settings on [this site](http://www.dnsinspect.com), I find these settings, which are correct in my opinion:

Your name servers returned 5 MX records:

```
1 aspmx.l.google.com. TTL=86400
5 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com. TTL=86400
5 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com. TTL=86400
10 alt3.aspmx.l.google.com. TTL=86400
10 alt4.aspmx.l.google.com. TTL=86400
```

Every test is green, nothing seems wrong. But if I test my dns on another ssl mailserver checksite, there is one server listed as a mailserver, which is the one which will be resolved by my domain. What is going wrong? The mails are still received from my frontend mailserver. But as the first test shows, the mails should go to google?!

I changed everything on this wednesday at 3 in the morning...

Comment: what was the old TTL before you changed?  Maybe the "ssl mailserver checksite" as well as others, have not received the updates yet.  Would really need more info for anyone to help you.

Answer (score 0):

TTL specifies the time interval that the resource record may be cached before the source of the information should again be consulted.

In BIND-9 this value is defined in the beginning of the zone file with the $TTL directive.

If this value are to high, the RR records expire to slowly and this can explain why some DNS answer correctly and others don't.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for you help so far! :)
I guess the TTL is always the same, because I can't set it thus it will default to the above value.
If I understand it right, the MX TTL can have a maximum value of 3 days right?
Well: wednesday 3am, thursday 3am, saturday 3am. Now it's Saturday 2PM. Tadaa. Nothing changed :(

My DNS settings are the following:

```
Subdomain   Type    Priority    Target
-/-         NS                  ns10.somens.com      
-/-         NS                  ns9.somens.com   
-/-         CNAME               myproxy.redirectme.net          
-/-         MX      5           ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM             
-/-         MX      5           ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM             
-/-         MX      10          ALT3.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM             
-/-         MX      10          ALT4.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM             
-/-         MX      1           ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM          
*           CNAME               myproxy.redirectme.net          
s1.pool     A                   xx.xx.xx.xx             
s2.pool     A                   xx.xx.xx.xx             
www         CNAME               myproxy.redirectme.net
```

The DynDNS myproxy.redirectme.net points to s1.pool, which is also runnign the "old" mailserver, which shouldn't receive emails anymore... Am I doing soething wrong?

Comment: If I read this right, it looks like you have (or try to have?) a `CNAME` at the zone apex, which is not valid (`CNAME` records cannot coexist with other data and the zone apex always has at least `SOA` and `NS` records, in your case `MX` as well). Regarding TTL, that's a 32 bit integer field specifying the time in seconds. The TTL can absolutely be set to more than 3 days.

Comment: Also, this does not look like an answer to the question. Should it rather be edited into the question?